# Compiling a kernel module for openvz VM?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, virtual-machine, openvz

I have an openvz machine which I am `root` on, it is a virtual machine I am `ssh` to:

```
>uname -a
Linux molo 2.6.32-042stab084.25 #1 SMP Wed Feb 12 16:04:42 MSK 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am trying to build an hello world kernel module:

### hello.c:

```
#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>         /* Needed for the macros */
static int __init hello_start(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Loading hello module...\n");
printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world\n");
return 0;
}
static void __exit hello_end(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye Mr.\n");
}
module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);
```

### Makefile:

```
obj-m = hello.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

And when I am trying to compile `hello.c`:

```
#make
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab084.25/build M=/local/my_modules modules
make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab084.25/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

That is the kernel version `uname -r` reports

```
#uname -r
2.6.32-042stab084.25
```

The following didn't help too:

```
$sudo apt-get install "linux-headers-$(uname -r)"
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-2.6.32-042stab084.25
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-2.6.32-042stab084.25'
```

Here is the `/lib/modules` directory:

## ls /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab084.25/

```
modules.alias      modules.ccwmap  modules.dep.bin  modules.ieee1394map  modules.isapnpmap  modules.pcimap    modules.softdep  modules.symbols.bin
modules.alias.bin  modules.dep     modules.devname  modules.inputmap     modules.ofmap      modules.seriomap  modules.symbols  modules.usbmap
```

Comment: Might be easier to get an appropriate response on askubuntu.com

Comment: Might be easier to ask your VPS provider for the development package.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams can't I find the development package by myself online?

Comment: @Shahbaz you right it is openvz machine

Answer (score 2):

Download and install linux-headers package from openvz page (more on http://openvz.org/Installation_on_Debian)

1) Add source

```
cat << EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvz-rhel6.list
deb http://download.openvz.org/debian wheezy main
# deb http://download.openvz.org/debian wheezy-test main
EOF
```

2) Install

```
wget http://ftp.openvz.org/debian/archive.key
sudo apt-key add archive.key
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install "linux-headers-$(uname -r)"
```

Remember that you can only do this from the "Host", not from inside of a OpenVZ VPS. Meaning that loading kernel drivers to kernel is only permitted from the Host and would affect all containers on that Host.

Comment: Thanks Alec, I would happy to select this answer, any chance you add more details? how to get it with apt-get, what is the sequence for installation? thanks

Comment: Didn't have a chance to test it on debian, please check the instructions on your machine to be sure

Comment: if you want without apt-get method then take kernel source code and give the path of kernel source in Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel doesn't appear to be one of the ones provided by Canonical, usually official kernels end with a version number or with the `generic` or other suffix.

Usually you find the package with the kernel headers under `pool/main/l` as you can see [here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-lts-saucy/) in the case of the `security` repository for Ubuntu Saucy.

You should ask the question to the person that provided the kernel that you are using, there is not that much you can do without more information unless you are willing to go for an officially supported kernel.